# Jquery add fields dynamically, if removed last element the fields are not added anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a conflict with jquery and can not find a correct solution, every time something breaks, i have a form that i add one input and one select at the time dynamically, by default the html form have on input and one select, and after adding new fields if is required.

The problem is that the fields are added dinamically with jquery and can be removed as well, but if you add a few new fields and remove just the last one the form will not be working anymore, can not be added new fields, but if you remove a field from the middle than it is fine is working.

**I need to fix if you remove even the last element to be abble to add again new fields.**

Please see the example below.

**HTML**

```
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            <span class="multiple-field-container-add">
                <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub">
                    <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                        <label>IBAN</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="0-iban" name="0-iban" type="text" value="">
                    </span>
                    <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw">
                        <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">
                            <label>Currency</label>
                            <select class="select select2-hidden-accessible" id="0-currency" name="0-currency" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="-">Select currency</option><option value="USD">USD</option><option value="EUR">EUR</option></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">
                            <a href="#" class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-custom-width multiple-add-input"><b><i class="icon-plus2"></i></b> Add new</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var next = 1;
$(".multiple-add-input").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var addto = "#" + next + "-iban";

    next = next + 1;
    var newIn = '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub">'+
                    '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw has-feedback has-feedback-left">'+
                       '<label>IBAN</label>'+
                        '<input class="form-control" id="' + (next) + '-iban" name="' + (next) + '-iban" type="text" value="">'+
                        '<div class="form-control-feedback">'+
                            '<i class="icon-font-size"></i>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw">'+
                        '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">'+
                            '<label>Currency</label>'+
                            '<select name="' + (next) + '-currency" id="' + (next) + '-currency" class="select">'+
                                    '<option value="EUR">EUR</option>'+
                                    '<option value="USD">USD</option>'+
                            '</select>'+
                        '</span>'+
                        '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">'+
                            '<div class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-custom-width remove-me" onclick="_multiple_field_remove_('+ (next) +')"><b><i class="icon-cancel-square2"></i></b> Remove</div>'+
                        '</span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</span>';

    alert(next);
    var newInput = $(newIn);

    $(addto).parent().parent().after(newInput);

    $('.select').select2();

    _multiple_field_remove_ = function(id){            
        alert(id);
           $('#'+ id +'-iban').parents('span.content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub').remove();                
};
```

Comment: Please add a JS-Fiddle

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? what is the value of `next` after you delete last item?

Comment: `$('.select').select2();` - what is this referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionluchian

the reason cause the issue,it's the number `next`.

when you delete the last element, and you click add button next,

```
var addto = "#" + next + "-iban";
...
// can't find item 'addto',so it's not work
$(addto).parent().parent().after(newInput);
```

this code can't find the last items at all.

Please use above instead:

```
change: $(addto).parent().parent().after(newInput);

to    : $('.multiple-field-container-add').append(newInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best looking end result, but its working

```js
$(function(){
  
    addElement(); 

});



function addElement(){
  
  $(".multiple-add-input").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).off('click');
    
    var next = parseInt($('.iban-input').last().attr('id'));    
   
    var addto = "#" + next + "-iban";
    next++;
    
    var newIn = '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub">'+
                    '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw has-feedback has-feedback-left">'+
                       '<label>IBAN</label>'+
                        '<input class="form-control iban-input" id="' + (next) + '-iban" name="' + (next) + '-iban" type="text" value="">'+
                        '<div class="form-control-feedback">'+
                            '<i class="icon-font-size"></i>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw">'+
                        '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">'+
                            '<label>Currency</label>'+
                            '<select name="' + (next) + '-currency" id="' + (next) + '-currency" class="select">'+
                                    '<option value="EUR">EUR</option>'+
                                    '<option value="USD">USD</option>'+
                            '</select>'+
                        '</span>'+
                        '<span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">'+
                            '<div class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-custom-width remove-me" id="remove-'+ (next) +'"><b><i class="icon-cancel-square2"></i></b> Remove</div>'+
                        '</span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                '</span>';
    
    // Add element
    $(addto).parent().parent().after(newIn);
    
    // Bind removing
    $('.remove-me')
      .off('click')   
      .on('click', function(){
        removeElement($(this).attr('id'));
      });
    
    // Bind adding
    addElement();
  
  });
}


function removeElement(id){
  $('#'+id).parent().parent().parent().remove();
}
```

```css
.content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            <span class="multiple-field-container-add">
                <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub">
                    <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                        <label>IBAN</label>
                        <input class="form-control iban-input" id="0-iban" name="0-iban" type="text" value="">
                    </span>
                    <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw">
                        <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">
                            <label>Currency</label>
                            <select class="select select2-hidden-accessible" id="0-currency" name="0-currency" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value="-">Select currency</option><option value="USD">USD</option><option value="EUR">EUR</option></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="content-panel-flat-raw-double-sub-raw-double-raw">
                            <a href="#" class="btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-custom-width multiple-add-input"><b><i class="icon-plus2"></i></b> Add new</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </form>
```